# Marketing my mobile game

Tags: marketing, google-play, appstore

I have almost finished my game; I want to upload it to Google Play and the App Store.  I will make it free but with Admob advertising.
What is the best way to market my app (without any app promotion companies)?
Please give me a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

A great way to get some cheap advertisement for your game out there, is to go out and buy a nice, large bell.  The initial investment might set you back about $20, but it will keep you out of having to deal with any pesky companies.

So the general concept, is to dress up in some clothing that will stand out in a crowd.  Then you would ring your bell and yell "Hear Ye!  Hear Ye!" to gather up a crowd around you.   Once you get people's attention, you can then talk about your game.

Try to be concise when you detail your game, as you don't want to bore people.  And remember to smile.

It is also a great idea to have hand-out material ready for people to pick up so that they can take that information with them.

Comment: you are funny today.

Comment: How is it free if you have to buy a bell?

Comment: @GillesV. The question did not specifically ask for free methods, but for a way to promote without the help of marketing companies.  Also, you could rent out the bell to other gamedevs once you are done, to generate some extra side income.  Essentially, if you do it right, the bell pays itself.

Comment: @Jon: I think that Gilles refers to the fact that you have called it "some free advertisement".

Comment: @Kaiserludi Fair point, I revised my answer.  Should be a little more clear now.  Thanks.

Comment: Gz for the post, it's very refreshing! I won't +1 though because it's not in the scope of the site :)

Comment: @Kaiserludi Yes I was referring the "free advertisement" in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Typically, developers that are on a budget and don't have a lot of money for advertisement will invest more time.

Here are some techniques used:

- Blog about it on their website
- Give news about it on their social network accounts (Twitter and Facebook)
- Give talks about it during game development conferences (E3, GDC, and more)
- Talk about it in webinars
- Do various fund-raising campaigns (Kickstarter)
- Participate in discussion forums and have links pointing to their game in their profile
- Comment posts of reviews on game review sites (such as IGN) (The idea is that they get to know you in order to be willing to review your game upon release)

The goal is to rise awareness and get as much potential players to follow you before the release of your game.

As you might have noticed, most of this must be started *long before* the game is released to hook as much as people as possible.

This has the advantage of getting feedback during the development of the game because people will comment on what you post.

Comment: I dont understand why I must start this process before  the game has released.                                                                                                       the people want to download the game,not to wait until it would released

Comment: @yaakovrubenchik Do companies like EA, Ubisoft, Microsoft and the like wait until the release date to talk about upcoming games? No. They talk about it long before the game is released. Some games have seen more than one E3. If people know your game is coming, you'll have more people download it at launch. (Sorry if you received a double poke; I had to fix a typo.)